# Rails date_field translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to find a way to translate the headers of the rails date_field.

```
<%= form_for @foo do |f| %>
   <%= f.date_field :startdate %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

I allready have my swedish locale and it works when outputting things in the view (eg: I18n.localize(@startdate, format: "%a %e %b")), but I can't find anywhere how to translate the date helper.

I'm on Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format is handled by the browsers because `f.date_field` generates an HTML5 `<input type="date" ... >` tag, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format), the browsers do not yet support custom formats.

Comment: Oh that explains it! I had my browser language set to english. I looked everywhere in the Rails documentation, but I didn't think of that.

Comment: You might check at the solution I proposed to you in my answer. It is fully functional across all browsers and supports internationalization

Answer (score 1):

If you need a translated version, skip the date field and use jquery datepicker:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails